# Connect to external SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, wcf

I'm writing Windows 10 Desktop app (UWP C#)

I try to access  database.

I read that I can't do it directly, but I can do it using WCF

I added WCF Service and added this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFtoDB
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        DataSet querySql();
    }
    public class Service : IService
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Запрос данных в TestTable 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <returns></returns> 

        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security =SSPI;");
        public DataSet querySql()
        {
            try
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                string strSql = "select Title, Text from TestTable";
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, sqlCon);
                sqlDa.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

My SQL database is on this adress (`144.76.133.122`)

Where is I need to write this adress?

And do I need to have table on BD or no?

Comment: please read this,you can't just connect only by ipaddress .You have to see whether it is a named instance or default instance..http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62165/i-cant-connect-to-my-servers-sql-database-via-an-ip-address

Comment: you need to replace in local by the way

Comment: Data Source= 144.76.133.122
Like this? @TheGameiswar

Comment: yes,but not sure it will work,try connecting from SSMS first and also read the link i gave

Comment: okay, I will read it. Also I have question.Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security =SSPI; Catalog what I need to write? SSMS is Integrated Security? @TheGameiswar

Comment: You will need to look at what each option means ,check out below links

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Okay, Thank's for help